# Which texts contain the following verses regarding the arrival and departure of goddess Durgā during Navarātris on different Vāhanas?

Tags: identification-request, durga, vahana, nava-durga

As per [this blog](http://www.acharyag.com/2020/10/blog-post_17.html?m=1) , we have the following verses in reference to the Vāhana (vehicle - mount) of goddess Durgā on which she’s said to arrive and depart during the Navarātris.

- Arrival

> शशिसूर्ये गजारूढ़ा शनिभौमे तुरंगमे ।
> गुरुशुक्रे च दोलायां बुधे नौका प्रकीर्तिता ॥
> फलम् - गजे च जलदा देवी छत्रभङ्ग तुरंगमे ।
> नौकायां सर्व सिद्धिस्यात् दोलायां मरणं धुव्रम् ॥
>
> > - If the Navarātri begin on a Sunday or Monday, then goddess Durgā arrives on an elephant, prophesying rainfall.
>
> > - On a Navarātri beginning on Saturday or Tuesday, the goddess arrives on a horse, prophesying a power transition.
>
> > - If the Navarātri begin on a Thursday or Friday, the goddess arrives on a palanquin, prophesying war, people’s suffering and bloody massacre.
>
> > - If the Navarātri begin on a Wednesday, the goddess arrives seated on a boat, prophesying overall prosperity and wellbeing of the devotees.

- Departure

The 'departure day' is to be taken as the day on which the Dashmi tithi falls.

> शशिसूर्यदिने यदि सा विजया महिषा गमनेरूज शोककरा । 
> शनिभौमे यदि सा विजया चरणायुधयानकरी विकला ॥
> बुधशुक्रे यदि सा विजया  गजवाहनगा शुभवृष्टिकरा । 
> सुरराजगुरौ यदि सा विजया नरवाहनगा शुभसौख्यकरा ॥
>
> > - If the day of goddess’s departure, i.e., the Dashmi tithi, coincides with a Sunday or Monday, then the goddess departs seated on a Buffalo,
> >   prophesying grief and misery.
>
> > - If the departure is on a Saturday or Tuesday, then the goddess departs on seated on a rooster, prophesying discomfort and perplexity
>
> > - If the departure is on a Wednesday or Friday, then the mount is an elephant, prophesying prosperous rains.
>
> > - If the departure coincides with a Thursday, the goddess departs on a Human, prophesying happiness & peace.

**Question is, which texts contain these descriptions?**

As per some sources of dubious accuracy, it's found in the Devī Bhāgavatapurāṇa, and/or a certain text called Medinī Jyotiṣa (or Muṇ‍ḍena Jyotiṣa), but I cannot locate it anywhere.

So, where are these verses found?

Comment: The Bengali Durga Puja which lasts for 4 days and takes place in October also follows the same rule. Bengali Panjika mentions the arrival and departure and the effect of each year. Eager to know the answer.

Comment: I did not know such a simple rule decides the outcome!

Comment: Haha, yes @AmritenduMukhopadhyay  maybe something similar to the Butterfly effect!!